# Docker custom registry with watchtower

Tags: docker, registry, containers, docker-watchtower

I have 2 VM in local network with Ubuntu OS. On one of them is installed Docker registry container with basic authentication (htpasswd) but without any certificates. Normally I'm accessing registry from other "client" machine and can pull the images. However, when I try to install watchtower on client machine it is immediately exiting

```
    root@ubnt-dckr:~# docker run --name watchtower -e DOCKER_HOST="tcp://192.168.88.12:5000" -e REPO_USER="myUser" -e REPO_PASS="myPass" v2tec/watchtower
    time="2019-01-16T08:11:18Z" level=fatal msg="Error response from daemon: 404 page not found"
```

Answer (score 1):

The default docker host ports are actually `2375` and `2376`.
Which is likely, why it's not working. Do not though, that `DOCKER_HOST` is not supposed to be used for *the docker registry* but rather *a remote docker engine*.

For private registries, see the second part of this page in the docs:
https://containrrr.github.io/watchtower/usage-overview/